# Recall/update view onDraw()

Tags: android, eclipse, ondraw, invalidation

I'm fairly new to programming in java. Right now I'm writing a little platformer game for class. The problem im facing is the following: I drew a little `bitmap` of a man to my `canvas`. if you touch the right half of the screen he should move right. same thing for the left side of the screen. im trying to recall the `onDraw` method in my seperate "`CanvasClass`" which extends the `View Class` and change the variables of the drawn `bitmap` everytime. 
Help me with the invalidate/postInvalidate method, i cant seem to understand it! thanks :)
GameActivity:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

CanvasClass ourView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            
    ourView = new CanvasClass(this);
    setContentView(ourView);     
}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    return false;
}
```

}

**CanvasClass:**

```
public class CanvasClass extends View implements OnTouchListener {

Bitmap mBackground, BackScaled,bobOri, bobScale;
int width, height,bobWidth = 33, bobHeight = 93;
float meX = 20,meY = 400;
Canvas canvas;

public CanvasClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ((Activity) getContext()).requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    height =displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background); 
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    BackScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackground, width, height,true);

    bobOri = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bobertfront);
    bobScale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bobOri, bobWidth,bobHeight, true);

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(BackScaled,0,0,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bobScale,20,410,null);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

    return true;
}
```

}

If you need anything else, please ask!
I will be checking every 5-10 minutes for replies, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What exaclty is your question?

To cause onDraw() to be called again you need to call invalidate(). The difference between invalidate and postInvalidate is that invalidate needs to be called from the UI thread and postInvalidate can be called from other threads...

In your case invalidate should do the trick.

reference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()
and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate()

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your need refresh onDraw implement onPause method